# How do I handle exceptions with Django objects.bulk_create()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am using `bulk_create`to create objects of a model. Whenever an exception is raised, how do I handle it?

```
aList = [
    Student(name="Jason"),
    Student(name="Mark"),
    Student(name="Tom"),
    Student(name="Jason"),
    Student(name="Tom"),
]

Student.objects.bulk_create(aList)
```

as the model has field `name` that is **`unique=True`**,  I have to process the inputs as the exception is raised. How do I handle exceptions one by one.

This don't work as intended,

```
try:
    # bulk_create
except:
    # handlers
```

as the exception is raised, the `bulk_create` process is terminated.

PS. I am looking forward for the **`bulk_create`**. **no loops with `create` or `update_or_create` or `get_or_create`**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django bulk_create with ignore rows that cause IntegrityError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451053/django-bulk-create-with-ignore-rows-that-cause-integrityerror/54189488)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's impossible. That's how `bulk_create` is defined:

```
def bulk_create(self, objs, batch_size=None):
        for parent in self.model._meta.get_parent_list():
            if parent._meta.concrete_model is not self.model._meta.concrete_model:
                raise ValueError("Can't bulk create a multi-table inherited model")
        if not objs:
            return objs
        self._for_write = True
        connection = connections[self.db]
        fields = self.model._meta.concrete_fields
        objs = list(objs)
        self._populate_pk_values(objs)
        with transaction.atomic(using=self.db, savepoint=False):
            if (connection.features.can_combine_inserts_with_and_without_auto_increment_pk
                    and self.model._meta.has_auto_field):
                self._batched_insert(objs, fields, batch_size)
            else:
                objs_with_pk, objs_without_pk = partition(lambda o: o.pk is None, objs)
                if objs_with_pk:
                    self._batched_insert(objs_with_pk, fields, batch_size)
                if objs_without_pk:
                    fields = [f for f in fields if not isinstance(f, AutoField)]
                    self._batched_insert(objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size)

        return objs
```

And the `_batched_insert`:

```
def _batched_insert(self, objs, fields, batch_size):
    """
    A little helper method for bulk_insert to insert the bulk one batch
    at a time. Inserts recursively a batch from the front of the bulk and
    then _batched_insert() the remaining objects again.
    """
    if not objs:
        return
    ops = connections[self.db].ops
    batch_size = (batch_size or max(ops.bulk_batch_size(fields, objs), 1))
    for batch in [objs[i:i + batch_size]
                  for i in range(0, len(objs), batch_size)]:
        self.model._base_manager._insert(batch, fields=fields,
                                         using=self.db)
```

So, as you can see `bulk_create` is basically a `for` loop inside an `transaction.atomic`.

One more thing. It is also impossible to save only some entries inside the transaction block. It either is executed fully or not executed at all.

Answer (score 4):

actually there is a flag `ignore_conflicts=False`, that catches exceptions,  so it makes sense to try `ModelName.objects.bulk_create([ModelName(name='spam', slug='eggs')...], ignore_conflicts=True)`

Answer (score 0):

you can handle it by just doing

```html
objs = [(Event), (Event), (Event)...]

try:
  Event.objects.bulk_create(objs)
except IntegrityError:
   for obj in objs:
    try:
      obj.save()
    except IntegrityError:
      continue
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).