# Catch Specific Failed Records in bulk_create Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, bulk, bulkupdate

I'm using bulk_create to insert thousand of users once:

```
new_users_bulk_list.append(User(user_id=user_id, date_of_birth=dob))
    if len(new_users_bulk_list) >= settings.BULK_LIMIT:
        try:
            User.objects.bulk_create(new_users_bulk_list)
            new_users_bulk_list[:] = []
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error: Creating users " + str(e))
```

and bulk_update to update many records:

```
user_bulk.append(user_sequence)
        if len(user_bulk) == settings.BULK_LIMIT:
            bulk_update(user_bulk)
            user_bulk[:] = []
```

If bulk_create or bulk_update fails in creating/updating records, how can I identify these failed records? Is there a way to catch specific failed records ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to do so. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451053/django-bulk-create-with-ignore-rows-that-cause-integrityerror) answer may give you some insight.

A far-from-perfect workaround I might suggest: manually split `new_users_bulk_list` into batches of some size. That may at least give you some degree of control over what's happening and what's failing.