# Bulk create with unique constraint -- ignore duplicates

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Let's say there's a model with unique constraint:

```
class A(models.Model):
    my_unique_value = models.CharField(unique=True)
```

I want to bulk_create As, but some of the my_unique_value values I'm inserting are already in the db. I want them to be ignored (not inserted).

What is the best, most efficient way to achieve that? I cannot insert them one by one, and catch Exceptions (it's too slow). I also cannot fetch all As to clean duplicates first.

The underlying DB is postgres.

Comment: Could you paste the view where you do it ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451053/django-bulk-create-with-ignore-rows-that-cause-integrityerror

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django bulk\_create with ignore rows that cause IntegrityError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451053/django-bulk-create-with-ignore-rows-that-cause-integrityerror)

Answer (score -3):

You can use [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), which as it names says - will only create if the item doesn't exist, otherwise it will fetch it. You can discard the fetched item.

Comment: That'll no longer be *bulk* create (it will make one query per object).

Comment: Yes but given your restrictions [a] cannot fetch and filter [b] don't want to duplicate, this is the best option available.