# Django get_or_create multiple rows without loops

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have an existing Django model which may or may not contain the results from a python calculation.

How do I test for and add multiple rows if it does not exist?

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) explain very nicely how to do one entry. Additionally there are various solutions for how to **insert** multiple rows.

I specifically need to (i) add bulk (ii) if it does not already exist.

If loops are the only way, then so be it.

Comment: you want a get_or_bulk_create which doesn't exist.

Comment: Good to know, loops it is then

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54189488/1420159